# SQL union tables based on date condition in either PHP or jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, query-builder

I am using jQuery [QueryBuilder](https://querybuilder.js.org/) plugin. Users can pull data based on the query they build as below :
[image]

In database, data of each year is stored in a separate table. For example : table_orders_2021,  table_orders_2020 ...

Currently, when a user submit a query so in my example `country = 'Austria' and [Order Entry Date] >= '2021-01-01'` I add the rule to the `where` clause and `union all` tables with the same rule as below :

```
   $rule = $_POST['rule'];
   $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM table_orders_2021 WHERE 1 = 1 AND " . $rule .
    " UNION ALL  
    SELECT * FROM table_orders_2020 WHERE 1 = 1 AND " . $rule .
    " UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM table_orders_2019 WHERE 1 = 1 AND " . $rule .
    " UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM table_orders_2018 WHERE 1 = 1 AND " . $rule
```

in my case the user chose orders from 2021 so no reason to union the other tables especially each table contains millions of rows.

The problem is : sometimes users build a rule without a date filter for example just `country = "Austria"` then I need to union all tables, sometimes they filter on multiple dates for example : `[Order Entry Date] >= '2019-07-01' AND [Order Entry Date] <= '2020-06-30'` then I need to `union all` 2019 and 2020 tables...

I want to create a dynamic solution which will union tables only in case of need and not union all tables by default.

My attempt was :

1. check if a rule contains a date, for example `'2021-` or `'2020-` or `'2019-`
2. get the operator before the `'2021-` or `'2020-`... for example if `>= '2020-` then union table 2020 and 2021, if `<= '2020-` then union 2020 and all previous tables

Before I finalize my work, I have in mind an advise from experts here would guide me if that's a good approach to follow. If someone has a suggestion a better approach please advise. It doesn't matter if do the checks will be in javascript/jQuery before submitting the rule or in PHP before I run the query on database. Thank you very much.

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not have a separate table for each year.  Instead, you should have one table with a column for the `year`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Unfortunately I can't update the data model. It was created by another team and that's how they set it up. I have only read access to the data. I should figue out what is the best approach in this situation

Comment: . . You should probably create a view that combines all the tables and just use the view.  Performance might not be as good, but the queries will be much simpler.